# CouchDB Install Errors Involving http.c on CentOS

Tags: centos, couchdb

I'm encountering errors when attempting to make and sudo make install for CouchDB 1.2.1 on CentOS release 5.10 (Final) x86_64 GNU/Linux with Linux kernel version 2.6.18-371.3.1.el5. I have the following dependencies installed/successfully executed the following to install dependencies:

```
Erlang R14B04 (erts-5.8.5) [source] [64-bit]
SpiderMonkey js-devel-1.70-8.el5.x86_64
curl 7.20.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)
sudo yum install autoconf
sudo yum install autoconf-archive
sudo yum install automake
sudo yum install curl-devel
sudo yum install erlang-asn1
sudo yum install erlang-erts
sudo yum install erlang-eunit
sudo yum install erlang-os_mon
sudo yum install erlang-xmerl
sudo yum install help2man
sudo yum install js-devel
sudo yum install libicu-devel
sudo yum install libtool
sudo yum install perl-Test-Harness
```

I then run the following as per the instructions:

```
wget http://archive.apache.org/dist/couchdb/1.2.1/apache-couchdb-1.2.1.tar.gz
tar -zxvf apache-couchdb-1.2.1.tar.gz
cd apache-couchdb-1.2.1
./configure
You have configured Apache CouchDB, time to relax.
Run `make && sudo make install' to install.
make && sudo make install
```

and get the following errors:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../.. -I../../../src/snappy/google-snappy   -D_XOPEN_SOURCE 
-I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -g -Wall -Werror -D_BSD_SOURCE
-I/usr/local/include -DXP_UNIX -DXP_UNIX -DJS_THREADSAFE -I/usr/include/xulrunner-17.0.10
-I/usr/include/nspr4    -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/include  -O2 -g -O2
-MT couchjs-http.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/couchjs-http.Tpo -c -o couchjs-http.o `test -f
'couch_js/http.c' || echo './'`couch_js/http.c
couch_js/http.c:101: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘jsint’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_ctor’:
couch_js/http.c:140: error: ‘HTTPData’ has no member named ‘last_status’
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
couch_js/http.c:142: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_SetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:142: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_SetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c:142: error: wrong type argument to unary exclamation mark
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_dtor’:
couch_js/http.c:162: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_GetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:162: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_GetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_open’:
couch_js/http.c:174: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_GetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:174: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_GetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_set_hdr’:
couch_js/http.c:246: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_GetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:246: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_GetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_send’:
couch_js/http.c:306: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_GetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:306: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_GetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘http_status’:
couch_js/http.c:334: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘JS_GetPrivate’ from incompatible pointer type
couch_js/http.c:334: error: too many arguments to function ‘JS_GetPrivate’
couch_js/http.c:341: error: ‘HTTPData’ has no member named ‘last_status’
couch_js/http.c: In function ‘recv_header’:
couch_js/http.c:548: error: ‘jsuint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
couch_js/http.c:548: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
couch_js/http.c:548: error: for each function it appears in.)
couch_js/http.c:548: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘hdrlen’
couch_js/http.c:558: error: ‘HTTPData’ has no member named ‘last_status’
couch_js/http.c:579: error: ‘hdrlen’ undeclared (first use in this function)
make[4]: *** [couchjs-http.o] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/username/apache-couchdb-1.2.1/src/couchdb/priv'
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/username/apache-couchdb-1.2.1/src/couchdb'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/username/apache-couchdb-1.2.1/src'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/username/apache-couchdb-1.2.1'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Has anybody encountered anything like this before? I poked around in http.c and noticed an include for curl/curl.h. I have a couple different versions of curl installed, but the most recent version shows up:

```
curl --version
curl 7.20.1 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.20.1 OpenSSL/0.9.8b zlib/1.2.3 libidn/0.6.5
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps http https imap imaps ldap pop3 pop3s rtsp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM SSL libz
```

I don't know if curl has something to do with the errors; maybe the version of CouchDB I am trying to install (from http://archive.apache.org/dist/couchdb/1.2.1/apache-couchdb-1.2.1.tar.gz) is to blame.

Answer (score 0):

You'd installed unsupported version of SpiderMonkey (17.0.10) while only 1.7.0 - 1.8.5 are supported.

To fix the issue reinstall js-devel and ensure that it has version 1.8.5 (it's recommended one). If you don't have any RPM against this version, you can make your own with help of [js185](https://github.com/wendall911/js185) project. (Or just grab it [here](http://packages.cloudant.com/rpm/latest/))

On second thought, you doing two wrong things. First, don't install anything via `make install` while you OS has system package manager. You can make proper RPM with help of [couchdb-rpm](https://github.com/wendall911/couchdb-rpm) project against the most recent CouchDB version - it's quite simple procedure. Second is CouchDB version itself - 1.2.1 had been released year ago and at this time 1.3, 1.4 and 1.5 releases happened (1.5.1 with important security fix) and 1.6 will be available in week or two. If you're going to install something, even with make install, try to pick the most recent versions, unless you have serious reasons for using outdated and not supported ones.